# My linux in WMware dose not have internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet-explorer, centos

I install Linux in VMWARE on a dedicated server but I do not have any internet connection. I can not ping anything. What should I do to have an internet connection?

I tried ubuntu, centos and different versions of them but still no internet connection. when I use the command
`IP a`
or
`ifconfig`.
It just show me a IO and nothing else.

Comment: You mean VMware, maybe?!? So you are not able to ping 127.0.0.1? What network setup have you chosen? Changing die guest OS will not help, if your VMware is not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this first go to this location

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
```

then use this command

```
ifconfig
```

you can see 2 flags one of them should be IO you should see what is the other flag name is. for example if it was eth0, in this location type

```
nano ifcfg-eth0
```

then paste this into this file remember change your IP, subnet mask and your gateway

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens33
UUID=e6dd2f58-fc77-497f-a7ce-28e35ac4ba52
DEVICE=ens33
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR= "YOUR IP"
PREFIX="SUBMASK"
GATEWAY="GATEWAY"
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

then restart your centos and you should have internet.